# Displaying an image associated with an artist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to display an image that is in my public/image folder and I
don't know how to.

What I want to do is to be able to assign a photo to an artist so you
can navigate through different artist's photo.

This is my image model

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :publishings
  has_many :artists, :through => :publishings
  has_many :comments,:through => :friends

  has_many :comments, :as => :resource, :class_name => "Commentable"
end
```

This is my image show.html

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <%= @image.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Filename:</b>
  <%= @image.filename %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Likes:</b>
  <%= @image.likes %>
</p>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_image_path(@image) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', images_path %>
```

This is the database for the images

```
class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :images do |t|
      t.string :title :null => false
      t.string :filename :null =>false
      t.integer :likes :default =>0

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :images
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= image_tag @image.filename %>
```